# imprimir dado especifico de um json no php

Tags: php, json

Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação para pegar os dados do cnpj na api da receita federal. Eu consigo trazer e imprimir todos os dados via json, o meu problema é que eu gostaria de imprimir apenas um dado especifico, que no caso seria o campo de email, como posso fazer isso ?

Segue o link da documentação da api https://receitaws.com.br/api

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/" . $linha['cnpj']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$retorno = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$retorno = json_decode($retorno); //Ajuda a ser lido mais rapidamente
echo json_encode($retorno, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Se possível anexe o retorno do echo, para que a comunidade possa lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Geralmente quando não definido `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPPER`, costuma dar erro, então com esse código você consegue pegar os dados:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/".$linha['cnpj']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
$retorno = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$retorno = json_decode($retorno);
echo $retorno->data_situacao;//aqui está um exemplo de um dado retornado da requisição
```

Answer (score 0):

$email= $retorno['email'];
Assim você pega somente o e-mail.

Você pode manusear o Json da forma que quiser para obter qualquer dado. Só se atente a como ele está estruturado. Por exemplo o "text" em "atividade_principal" está dentro de uma lista, então é uma abordagem diferente para pegar esse campo.